# How to check if a wav file is mono or stereo in js?

Tags: javascript

I made a player that shows waveform images using the wavesurfer plugin. I also made a function to mute the volume for each channel by splitting the channels of the wav file. However, in the first place, I did not think of the case where wav files are not stereo. If the wav file is not stereo, I do not want to split the channels of the wav file, and I want to hide the mute function for each channel. (Since it doesn't work in the first place, even if there is, it seems like the user will say "Something doesn't work?") Is there any way to implement this with js?
Even if I google it, only a way to divide the audio by channel comes up, but there is no way to determine whether the wav file is stereo or mono in the first place. help...

By googling, I searched for a way to determine whether a wav file is stereo or mono with js.

Comment: You could try [music-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/music-metadata#trackinfoaudiotrack) npm package to determine amount of channels in your file.